# Anime style video with pink alien girl who gets abducted. Two other aliens rap

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I was standing in line at Six Flags and they had a show playing that took place in space. It was animated in a sort of anime-style.

There were two aliens wearing helmets and they were rapping(?). There was a sphere-shaped spaceship that could project holograms. There was a pink alien girl. She was on her own world before she was teleported away/kidnapped(?).

I took a photo of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was this?  The photo is of a monitor displaying this show?  How long was it?  (Was it a clip, a trailer, or an on-going show you only caught part of?)

Comment: Hi, David! This was Yesterday evening (December 30th), Yes the photo is a screenshot of a 3 second recording of the show. I only caught part of the show before having to move on.

Comment: Would you post whole 3 seconds somewhere, say, on youtube? youtube itselft may claim video, and tell you its source.

Comment: @Valorum lol did the same =)

Answer (score 3):

This is the song *La La La* by the band [Area21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area21).

> The song's music video introduced the animated characters, which are
> aliens named M and M.
>
> [image]